# Invalid spring-boot-dependency version when using jgitver and local repo in maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jgitver

When I use spring-boot-starter-parent combined with local repository and jgitver I get the following error:

```
[ERROR]   The project tmplsvcpkg:TMPL_SVC_NAME-parent:0.0.0-27-a592e4fb-feature_gitlabci-dirty (/home/user/git/service-template/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]   Non-resolvable parent POM for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:0.0.0-27-a592e4fb-feature_gitlabci-dirty in internal-repository (https://mvnrepo) @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:[unknown-version], /home/user/git/service-template/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.2.0.RELEASE.pom, line 3, column 11 -> [Help 2]
```

Note **unknown-version** for spring-boot-starter-parent and **0.0.0-27-a592e4fb-feature_gitlabci-dirty** for spring-boot-dependencies. The 0.0.0-27-... version is the version calculated by the jgitver. It looks like the version resolution gets messed up somehow. If I change the local repository to any directory outside of my project it starts working again. If I supress jgitver it starts working again. If I define the local repo even deeper in my project (like maven.repo.local=x/y/z/.m2/repository, the error is still present.

I defined the parent in my pom.xml in this way:

```
        <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>
```

And I run my maven in this way:

```
mvn compile -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository -U
```

If I add jgitver.skip=true, everything works.

I suspect it might have something to do with the fact that spring-boot-starter parent defines it's parent (spring-boot-dependencies) as relative to it's position:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath>../../spring-boot-dependencies</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Has anyone any ideas why it might be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe your local repo is corrupt.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a case as I delete the local repo before every test and no matter how many times I repeat my attemts, the results are the same. Jgitver + local repo inside project = error, jgitver + local repo outside the project = success.

Comment: I'm sorry then I cannot help. Never used Jgitver. May I ask why you use it?

Comment: It calculates the version of a maven artifact based on where in the git structure it is located. Branches get different versions, uncommited repos get different versions, tags get different versions. It's a great way of making sure the versions are consistent across the whole project and they reflect the actual version of an artifact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it's a well known issue and is resolved by a certain configuration of the plugin (you have to exclude the .m2 directory in plugin config). More details are in this issue:

https://github.com/jgitver/jgitver-maven-plugin/issues/60